# shell script for moving selected files from one directory to another

Tags: shell-script, mv

I've a requirement in which I have to move particular files from one directory to another. I'm having the list of desired files in a file "req_files.txt"

```
prev_dir=/cygdrive/c/Users/abhisek.samanta/Desktop/New_folder
new_dir=/cygdrive/c/Users/abhisek.samanta/Desktop/New
cd $prev_dir
for i in `cat req_files.txt`
do
   mv $prev_dir/$i $new_dir
done
```

But I'm getting below error :

```
mv: cannot stat `/cygdrive/c/Users/abhisek.samanta/Desktop/New_folder/dbo.account_address_adt.Table\r': No such file or directory
```

I tried the command for removing the line break problem, but still its not working:

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' test.sh
```

Comment: Is `tr` installed? It should be. If so, you can do `tr -d '\r' < req_files.txt > no_dos_list.txt` to remove the dos line returns. The next question is, do you have files with a space in their name?

Comment: Yes, tr is there. No my filename is not having any spaces. They have _ in the filenames.

Comment: Please provide an example of the `req_files.txt` file

Comment: Contents are like below :

dbo.account_adt.Table.sql
dbo.account_currency_adt.Table.sql
dbo.account_sub_type_adt.Table.sql
and so on

Answer (score 1):

First of all for removing `\r` from the file name you can try:

```
FILENAME=$(echo $FILENAME|tr -d '\r')
```

- `-d`  delete characters

And i suggest to use this way in iteration:

```
while read filename ; do
    filename=$(echo $filename |tr -d '\r')
    mv $prev_dir/$filename $new_dir
done < $prev_dir/req_files.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... but the loop is not iterating... It's only picking up the first file which it's finding, not the rest of them.

Comment: @AbhisekSamanta not iterating !
its going throw every line in the file, and i think that is iterating !

Comment: How does your `req_files.txt` look like`? Add some lines to your question. It would also be save to double-quote the variables, just in case there are some special characters in the name.

Comment: @WissamAl-Roujoulah  It's only working on the first file which it's getting from the "req_files.txt" and not working on rest of them.....

Comment: @Thomas : req_files contains file names like below :

Comment: try `while IFS=" " read filename;do ` . Post req_files.txt contents.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou : Contents are like below :

dbo.account_adt.Table.sql
dbo.account_currency_adt.Table.sql
dbo.account_sub_type_adt.Table.sql
and so on....

Comment: @AbhisekSamanta does all files name end with .sql ?
and is there is a problem if i suggest an answer with `awk` ?

Answer (score 0):

I am getting done with below code shared yesterday please see o/p below: share your error

```
[root@rhel1 New_folder]# ll
total 12
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   0 Dec  7 23:34 1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   0 Dec  7 23:34 3
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   0 Dec 30 16:34 new folder1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   0 Dec 30 16:34 new folder2
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   0 Dec 30 16:34 new folder3
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  11 Dec  8 01:13 req_files.txt
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 231 Dec  8 01:22 tesh.sh
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 135 Dec  8 01:21 test1.sh
[root@rhel1 New_folder]# cat req_files.txt
New folder
[root@rhel1 New_folder]# vi req_files.txt
[root@rhel1 New_folder]# sh -x tesh.sh
++ echo -en '\n\b'
+ IFS='                                                                                                                                                                '
+ prev_dir=/cygdrive/c/Users/abhisek.samanta/Desktop/New_folder
+ new_dir=/cygdrive/c/Users/abhisek.samanta/Desktop/New
+ cd /cygdrive/c/Users/abhisek.samanta/Desktop/New_folder
++ cat req_files.txt
+ for i in '`cat req_files.txt`'
+ mv '/cygdrive/c/Users/abhisek.samanta/Desktop/New_folder/new folder1' /cygdrive/c/Users/abhisek.samanta/Desktop/New/
+ for i in '`cat req_files.txt`'
+ mv '/cygdrive/c/Users/abhisek.samanta/Desktop/New_folder/new folder2' /cygdrive/c/Users/abhisek.samanta/Desktop/New/
+ for i in '`cat req_files.txt`'
+ mv '/cygdrive/c/Users/abhisek.samanta/Desktop/New_folder/new folder3' /cygdrive/c/Users/abhisek.samanta/Desktop/New/
+ IFS=
[root@rhel1 New_folder]# ll
total 12
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   0 Dec  7 23:34 1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   0 Dec  7 23:34 3
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  36 Dec 30 16:34 req_files.txt
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 231 Dec  8 01:22 tesh.sh
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 135 Dec  8 01:21 test1.sh
[root@rhel1 New_folder]# ll ../New/
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Dec  7 23:34 2
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Dec  7 23:34 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Dec  7 23:34 5
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Dec  8 00:56 New folder
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Dec 30 16:34 new folder1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Dec 30 16:34 new folder2
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Dec 30 16:34 new folder3
[root@rhel1 New_folder]#
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for taking their valuable timing in sorting my problem out. I'd like to share the way I solved it :

```
prev_dir=/cygdrive/c/Users/abhisek.samanta/Desktop/Table_scripts
new_dir=/cygdrive/c/Users/abhisek.samanta/Desktop/New
cd $prev_dir
for i in `cat req_files.txt`
do
   sed -i 's/\r$//' $i 
   echo $i
   cd $prev_dir
   mv $i $new_dir
done
```

The same old short code ran without much tweaks. Thank you all for your sincere cooperation. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a couple of days old, but I'm not sure the shell loops are necessary, as the sed command can read through the whole file on its own, before using something like xargs to combine all the files into a single mv command:

```
prev_dir=/cygdrive/c/Users/abhisek.samanta/Desktop/Table_scripts
new_dir=/cygdrive/c/Users/abhisek.samanta/Desktop/New

cd ${prev_dir}
sed 's/\r$//' filelist | xargs mv -t $new
```

Here, using the given directories, and the `sed` command you have found works, then as everything is piped into `xargs`, it will add each line from the pipe onto the `mv` command, which can take multiple files and then move them all to the directory given with the `-t` flag

```
$ > cat movefile.sh 
new="$(pwd)/dir1/"
sed 's/\r$//' filelist | xargs mv -t $new
$ > cat -v filelist 
file1^M
file2^M
file3^M

$ > touch file{1,2,3}
$ > ls -l
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 grownups users 4096 Jan  1 22:29 dir1
-rw-r--r-- 1 grownups users    0 Jan  1 22:30 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 grownups users    0 Jan  1 22:30 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 grownups users    0 Jan  1 22:30 file3
-rw-r--r-- 1 grownups users   22 Jan  1 22:26 filelist
-rwxr--r-- 1 grownups users   61 Jan  1 22:29 movefile.sh
$ > ls dir1/
$ > ./movefile.sh 
$ > ls -l dir1/
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 grownups users 0 Jan  1 22:30 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 grownups users 0 Jan  1 22:30 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 grownups users 0 Jan  1 22:30 file3
$ >
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use IFS which determines field separator.

```
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
prev_dir=/cygdrive/c/Users/abhisek.samanta/Desktop/New_folder
new_dir=/cygdrive/c/Users/abhisek.samanta/Desktop/New
cd $prev_dir
for i in `cat req_files.txt`
do
   mv $prev_dir/$i $new_dir/
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Comment: It's only working on the first file which it's getting from the "req_files.txt" and not working on rest of them.....